# Activate my plugins via FTP

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

Hi I have disabled all my plugins to try and determine a plugin conflit and ended up breaking my site with one click!

I have searched arrond to find people saying that you can turn them om via FTP.

I think I have found my "`active plugins`" tasble in phpmyadmin and it reads as follows

```
a:1:{i:4;s:27:"cornerstone/cornerstone.php";}
```

But I have all these in my plugins folder and they were all active before.

**File path:**
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/business-worldpay-gateway-for-woocommerce
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cornerstone
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/really-simple-captcha
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/remove-query-strings-from-static-resources
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revision-control
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/simple-301-redirects
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/simple-custom-css
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/updraftplus
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-order-delivery
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woothemes-updater
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo-premium
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-optimize
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-smushit
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/x-content-dock
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/x-custom-404
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/x-facebook-comments
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/x-google-analytics
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/x-smooth-scroll
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/advanced-cache.php
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/index.php

How do I turn all those on? Sorry I know it is a big ask!
Could anyone tell me if I can activate my plugings again from here please?

Thanks

Ben

Comment: may this helps http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199798/activate-a-plugin-through-phpmyadmin-or-ftp

Comment: You can do this with `functions.php` easily. See this post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/how-to-activate-plugins-via-code?rq=1#answer-4050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below mysql query to activate your plugin:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'a:22:{i:0;s:19:"akismet/akismet.php";i:1;s:58:"contact-form-7-to-database-extension/contact-form-7-db.php";i:2;s:36:"contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php";i:3;s:27:"js_composer/js_composer.php";i:4;s:23:"revslider/revslider.php";i:5;s:23:"soliloquy/soliloquy.php";i:6;s:27:"updraftplus/updraftplus.php";i:7;s:41:"wordpress-importer/wordpress-importer.php";i:8;s:24:"wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php";i:9;s:25:"wp-smushit/wp-smushit.php";i:10;s:33:"x-content-dock/x-content-dock.php";i:11;s:29:"x-custom-404/x-custom-404.php";i:12;s:39:"x-disqus-comments/x-disqus-comments.php";i:13;s:39:"x-email-mailchimp/x-email-mailchimp.php";i:14;s:43:"x-facebook-comments/x-facebook-comments.php";i:15;s:41:"x-google-analytics/x-google-analytics.php";i:16;s:43:"x-olark-integration/x-olark-integration.php";i:17;s:29:"x-shortcodes/x-shortcodes.php";i:18;s:35:"x-smooth-scroll/x-smooth-scroll.php";i:19;s:45:"x-under-construction/x-under-construction.php";i:20;s:29:"x-video-lock/x-video-lock.php";i:21;s:31:"x-white-label/x-white-label.php";}' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';
```

But as you say 'determine a plugin conflit and ended up breaking my site' I suggest you to follow below steps:

**1 De-activate All Plugins via phpmyadmin**
In the options table, find the `option_name` column and find find the line named `active_plugins`. On the `active_plugins` line, click edit. You will see something similar to this:

```
a:22:{i:0;s:19:"akismet/akismet.php";i:1;s:58:"contact-form-7-to-database-extension/contact-form-7-db.php";i:2;s:36:"contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php";i:3;s:27:"js_composer/js_composer.php";i:4;s:23:"revslider/revslider.php";i:5;s:23:"soliloquy/soliloquy.php";i:6;s:27:"updraftplus/updraftplus.php";i:7;s:41:"wordpress-importer/wordpress-importer.php";i:8;s:24:"wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php";i:9;s:25:"wp-smushit/wp-smushit.php";i:10;s:33:"x-content-dock/x-content-dock.php";i:11;s:29:"x-custom-404/x-custom-404.php";i:12;s:39:"x-disqus-comments/x-disqus-comments.php";i:13;s:39:"x-email-mailchimp/x-email-mailchimp.php";i:14;s:43:"x-facebook-comments/x-facebook-comments.php";i:15;s:41:"x-google-analytics/x-google-analytics.php";i:16;s:43:"x-olark-integration/x-olark-integration.php";i:17;s:29:"x-shortcodes/x-shortcodes.php";i:18;s:35:"x-smooth-scroll/x-smooth-scroll.php";i:19;s:45:"x-under-construction/x-under-construction.php";i:20;s:29:"x-video-lock/x-video-lock.php";i:21;s:31:"x-white-label/x-white-label.php";}
```

Cut that code and click Go. Now all the plugins are successfully Inactivated.

**2 Determine the cause plugin**
Now the best way to determine which plugin is causing the issue is to enable each plugin one by one via your *WordPress admin login page > Go to Plugins > Installed Plugins > Enable a plugin* one by and check you website front every time.

Hope this work for you

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for getting back to me, So I tried deleting all the text in the box, the site still won't respond, I tried entering your code that you kindly gave me but it still won't work.
Thanks for your kind help though

Comment: Ok, follow my given steps _1 De-activate All Plugins via phpmyadmin_ and _2 Determine the cause plugin_ to determine and resolved this caused plugin issues.

Comment: OMG I am so sorry to have wasted y6our time I was looking in the wrong database the onlt item in the "active_plugins" is : a:1:{i:4;s:27:"cornerstone/cornerstone.php";}

However I have all these in my plugins folder:

Comment: I have had to update the question as my comments were too long,

Comment: Glad to help you Ben!

Answer (score 1):

In FTP, rename:

1. `wp-content/themes` to `wp-content/themes-tmp`
2. `wp-content/plugins` to `wp-content/plugins-tmp`

...at this point, you should be able to log back in/get at your dashboard (the front end of your site will be completely dead at this point, that's ok).

So now you're in, go to "Plugins" - this will ensure that WP permanently deactivates all plugins, now that they are technically no longer installed (from having renamed the directory).

Back in FTP, restore the `plugins` directory, leave `themes-tmp` alone. Then back again to WordPress, and reactivate all your required plugins.

Now finally back to FTP to restore `themes`.

Comment: Thank you so much! you have saved the day! Please let me know if there is anyway I might repay your kindness!

Comment: No worries, glad to help