# How to fix "There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions"?

Tags: errors

When I update my page I see this error and I tried to fix it but that didn't work. I removed all plugins and checked but it was still not fixed. Then I removed all themes and installed another theme but still it is not fixed. Now I am confused how to fix it. Please guide me how to fix it and why this error is showing?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/category/troubleshooting/

Comment: you can set the PHP version high in MultiPHP Manager in cpanel.

Answer (score 9):

You should troubleshoot your website for plugins and WordPress Themes.

Make sure your PHP version is 7.3 or above.

As you are unable to access your WordPress admin area so please try to access your file manager in cPanel or access public_html directory via FTP. Plugins and Themes directories are inside wp-content/ directories.

Go to wp-content/ Directory them rename plugins/ directory to pluginsbackup/ now try to load your site. If this works that means you have problem with a plugin.

If problem is with plugin change back the directory name pluginsbackup/ to plugins/ Enter in plugin directory. Now rename each plugins directory by placing backup at end of that directory name.

Once you have changed all plugins directories names, start getting original directory names one by one and make sure you check the website if that’s still working after each plugin start working. As soon as you see which plugin is making problem just delete that plugin.

Source [There has been a critical error on your website](https://www.webfulcreations.com/there-has-been-a-critical-error-on-your-website/).

If you can't figure out what's wrong please turn on the wp debug mode so you can get details of error. Edit your wp-config.php from WordPress root using FTP. And

Find in **wp-config.php**

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

And replace with

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Once you turn on the wp debug mode you are not able to see the details of issue, weather is related to some missing file or some plugin is producing the FATAL error you can track and apply appropriate fix. Thanks. Once problem is fixed don't forget to turn off the debug mode in `wp-config.php`

Comment: all is good, but what are the 'Thanks' means in the answer context? :)

Comment: Thanks means Thank you for reading my answer :)

Comment: When adding a comment it states the following: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like '+1' or 'Thanks' ". Therefore I suggest the same applies to answers. Can you edit it and remove that phrase? just to add I like the rest of the troubleshooting tips, but believe that the community rule applies for the answers as well.

Answer (score 2):

That may not be a valid error. But the troubleshooting link provided in a comment to your question is a good place to start. Error logs are great help.

You should also provide additional info (edit your question). When does this happen? All pages? Admin area only? Alternate Tuesdays?

Make sure that you install themes/plugins only from the WP repository. There have been instances of malware'd plugins/themes causing problems.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I fixed the error by increasing the memory_limit and upload_max_filesize and it solved the problem quickly! Thank you to all guys here who made the ways for me!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I resolved this same issue when it completely logged me out of my site:
- Install wp-rollback plugin via FTP or Cpanel > File Manager
- To activate the plugin, follow this instruction here: [Activate a plugin through PHPMyAdmin or FTP?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199798/activate-a-plugin-through-phpmyadmin-or-ftp)

Good luck!